# Set width on <td> which under <th> with colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'd like to set width on the `td` in `tbody` which is underneath `thead` that has `colspan="2"` with an hard defined column width in %. The browser shell not dynamically adjust table width.

```css
.sample {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sample td:nth-child(1),
.sample th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}

.sample td:nth-child(2),
.sample th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<table class="sample" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>30%</td>
      <td>70%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above style works if `thead` is removed but does not work with it.

Important notes,

- I added the `table-layout: fixed;` since I need the columns to be exactly as width as specified. Using `table-layoud: auto;` results in the browser taking the specified width as on orientation but still dynamically adjusting width.

EDIT

The accepted answer solved my question above. However I'm not able to use `colgroup` since I'm using a WYSIWYG editor. Thus I added a follow up question with detailed specifications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371945/set-forced-width-with-css-on-td-which-is-under-th-with-colspan-without-using).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags:

```css
.sample {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="sample" border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:30%;">
    <col style="width:70%;">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>30%</td>
      <td>70%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your css that is so confusing for me. change it to follow

```
 .sample {width: 100%;}
.sample td:nth-child(1) {width:30%;}
.sample td:nth-child(2) {width:70%;}
```

of you wish that table looks good then you can give border so that u have clear idea about it.

```
<table class="sample" border="1px grey solid">
..
</table>
```

Comment: Not possible! I need fixed forced table widths. And yes it confuses me too!