# Set forced width with css on <td> which is under <th> with colspan without using colgroup

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'd like to set width on the `td` in `tbody` which is underneath `thead` `th` that has a `colspan="2"` with an hard defined column width in %. The browser shell not dynamically adjust table width if the cell content exceeds with.

```css
.sample {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sample td:nth-child(1),
.sample th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}

.sample td:nth-child(2),
.sample th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<table class="sample" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>30% This columns has a lot of content and a really long woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooord which is not wrapable by the browser by default. This column still should be 30%with.</td>
      <td>70%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above style works if `thead` is removed but does not work with it.

Important notes,

- I added the `table-layout: fixed;` since I need the columns to be exactly as width as specified. Using `table-layoud: auto;` results in the browser taking the specified width as on orientation but still dynamically adjusting width if table content exceeds the available width.
- `colgroup` and `col` can not be used since I'm using a wysiwyg editor which is not adding colgroups. Thus I rely on css.

This is a follow up question, since new conditions came up during my initial question [Set width on <td> which under <th> with colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346147/set-width-on-td-which-under-th-with-colspan)